# How can I use entityActionFactory in action files for customizing actions in ngrx/data?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

I saw we can **customize** our **actions** in **ngrx/data** like below

https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-actions#tagging-the-entityaction

[image]

Therefore, my **question** is how could I **create** these **customized actions** in the normal *****.actions.ts** files (**example**)

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

export const normalFooAction = createAction(
  ‘[Foo] foo’,
  props<{ foo: string }>()
);

¿¿¿
    export const customizedNRGXDataAction = createAction(
    ———
    this.entityActionFactory.create<Hero>(
      'Hero',
      EntityOp.QUERY_ALL,
      null,
      { tag: 'Load Heroes On Start' }
    );
    ———
???
```

through **entityActionFactory** as I wrote before to then use it in a **effect?** (**example**)

```
    @Injectable()
        export class FooEffects {
         ***
¿¿¿
          loadCustomizedNRGXDataAction$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(FooActions.customizedNGRXDataAction),
???
           ***
             ))
            )
          );
```

Is that **possible?**

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create it as an object in your store and then provide into your module via `useValue` to share it with modularized services.

```js
export const myEntityActionFactory = new EntityActionFactory();
// to avoid duplicates you need to assign it to window.myEntityActionFactory and create a getter function.

// use it somewhere.
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EntityDataModule.forRoot(...),
  ],
  provides: [
    {
      provide: EntityActionFactory,
      useValue: myEntityActionFactory,
    },
  ],
})
```